# jQuery selector not this child

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, click, children

Is there any way to attach a click event to several elements, and then have all children to the element, except children of THIS (the one clicked), to run a function?

That's a terrible explanation, but I'm looking for something like this:

```
$(".block_header").click(function(){
    $(".block_header span:not(this span)").toggleClass("collapse expand");
    $(".container:not(this+div.container)").slideToggle();
});
```

Here's a sample HTML:

```
<h3 id="sender_header" class="block_header"><span>Sender</span></h3>
<div id="sender_container" class="container">
    <p>Show or hide this, based on which H3 is clicked.</p>
</div>
<h3 id="receiver_header" class="block_header"><span>Receiver</span></h3>
<div id="receiver_container" class="container">
    <p>Show or hide this, based on which H3 is clicked.</p>
</div>
<h3 id="delivery_header" class="block_header"><span>Delivery</span></h3>
<div id="delivery_container" class="container">
    <p>Show or hide this, based on which H3 is clicked.</p>
</div>
<h3 id="items_header" class="block_header"><span>Items</span></h3>
<div id="items_container" class="container">
    <p>Show or hide this, based on which H3 is clicked.</p>
</div>
.... etc, etc (many more of the same)
```

Hope this isn't too complicated. It would save me a LOT of code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rather than excluding the element in the selector, you can use the [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not) function, which accepts a DOM element or jQuery object to remove from the jQuery set.

```
$(".block_header").click(function(e) {
    $('.block_header span').not($(this).find('span')).toggleClass("collapse expand");

    $('.container').not($(this).next()).slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I found this very helpful

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(this).parent('h3').siblings('h3').children('span').addClass('active');
$(this).parent('h3').siblings('h3').next('div.container').slideToggle('active');
```

That should do the trick!

However, can I assume that you will only ever have one active?

If that is the case, this is the easiest:

```
$('.active').removeClass('active').parent('h3').next('div.container').slideUp();
```

Hope that helps :)

**edit:**

To be extra clever, store the active one as a variable. So on click:

```
$active = $(this);
```

Then, next time you can do this, without getting jQuery to go finding the element again:

```
$active.removeClass('active').parent('h3').next('div.container').slideUp();
$active = $(this);
```

Comment: Holy cow you guys are brilliant! So many useful answers. Thanks so much! Oh, and yes: only one will ever be active at a time.

Comment: I want to vote yours up but I need 15 reputation and all I have is 11. Sorry. If I could mark two solutions as "solved" I would pick yours as well for so many great tips. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".block_header").click(function(){
    $(".block_header span").not($('span', this)).toggleClass("active");
    $(".container").not($(this).next()).slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like

```
 $(".block_header").not(this).find("span").toggleClass("collapse","expand");

 $(".container").not(this).not("div.container").slideToggle();
```